# Changing theme on vs2022 affects vs2019

Tags: themes, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I installed [DarkTheme2019](https://github.com/madskristensen/DarkTheme2019).  When I switch to it, it changes my VS2019 theme to "Blue".  In VS2019, I switch back to "Dark" and then in VS2022 it goes from "Dark(2019)" to "Dark".

VS2022 at least kept the font change from "Dark(2019).

Is there a way to have the two Visual Studio's not be affected by what the other does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2022-setting-the-theme-in-2022-chang/1466144

It's not fixed yet (in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.1.0) regardless of what that page says.

Comment: Any further information on this?  Still not working as of Sept. 7th 2022.

Comment: @Kixoka I have added new information in a new answer

Answer (score 5):

There now (Sept 2022) appears to be a fix for this.

In the current VS 2022 (Version 17.3.4), go to **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Accounts** and deselect the option to **"Synchronize Visual Studio settings across devices and installs on this machine..."**

Unchecking this option enabled me to have a theme for VS2022 different from the theme for VS2019.